# How can i read MTL file in R

Tags: r

I am very much new to R programming kindly someone tell how can i read the MTL file which is archived with landsat satellite data.

Answer (score 3):

For standard MTL file provided with Landsat scenes obtained from [EarthExplorer](http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/) or [Glovis](http://glovis.usgs.gov/) sevices, you could simply do:

```
mtl <- read.delim('L71181068_06820100518_MTL.txt', sep = '=', stringsAsFactors = F)
```

So, for something starting like this:

```
GROUP = L1_METADATA_FILE  GROUP = METADATA_FILE_INFO...
```

You may use this:

```
> mtl[grep("LMAX",mtl$GROUP),]
                  GROUP L1_METADATA_FILE
64          LMAX_BAND1           293.700
66          LMAX_BAND2           300.900
68          LMAX_BAND3           234.400
70          LMAX_BAND4           241.100
72          LMAX_BAND5            47.570
74         LMAX_BAND61            17.040
76         LMAX_BAND62            12.650
78          LMAX_BAND7            16.540
80          LMAX_BAND8           243.100
84       QCALMAX_BAND1             255.0
86       QCALMAX_BAND2             255.0
88       QCALMAX_BAND3             255.0
90       QCALMAX_BAND4             255.0
92       QCALMAX_BAND5             255.0
94      QCALMAX_BAND61             255.0
96      QCALMAX_BAND62             255.0
98       QCALMAX_BAND7             255.0
100      QCALMAX_BAND8             255.0
```

There are dictionaries provided by each service, found [here](https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/landsat_dictionary.html) and [here](http://glovis.usgs.gov/ImgViewer/landsat_dictionary.html).

Information from MTL may be critical for applying atmospheric and radiometric correction. By the way, [landsat](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/landsat/index.html) package allows you to run some of more typical correction using `DOS()` and `radiocorr()` functions.

You will also need standard calibration values provided by [Chander et al. (2009)](http://landsathandbook.gsfc.nasa.gov/pdfs/Landsat_Calibration_Summary_RSE.pdf).

For more complex approaches [this](http://www.fs.fed.us/pnw/pubs/journals/pnw_2006_schroeder001.pdf) may be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

The MTL file contains only metadata (I hope you knew that :-))  and is a plain text file, so you could just read it in and parse as desired.   If you are reasonably familiar with Matlab, you could port this tool  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39073  , converting it into `R` code.

EDIT:  I can't tell from your comments what you actually need. Here's an example MTL.txt file I pulled off the net:
http://landsat.usgs.gov/images/squares/processing_level_of_the_Landsat_scene_I_have_downloaded1.jpg

If you look at it, you can see the names and values of the data items.  If those are what you want, perhaps the easiest way to get them would be to  run the command

```
mtl.values <- read.table('filename.txt' , sep='=')
```

Which will give you a 2-column dataframe, with names in first column and values in the second.

Comment: Yeap i knew it dear but i want to read it so that if i have to calculate NDVI, the tool will read info from MTL file only and do it from itself, no need to give bands and no need to create stack in that case...if you can help on that because i don't have much knowledge on matlab cause i am very much new in programming.

Comment: Ok, -- if you can edit your question to specify which fields (data items) you want to extract from the header, we can probably write a 'filter' function to get you the right data.

Comment: okay, like i want to stack the image first and on the whole image i have to calculate NDBI, NDWI, and some other indices from the data, for which i think i should need bands information only....

Comment: Please post a sample MTL file that you are using and I'll put up some code to pull the items of interest for you.

Comment: I was using this but you can take anyone you are having i just need to how can we call and thank you for your reponses. You are really helpful thanks!!:)
L5146040_04020110305_MTL

Comment: To help out answerers, and to make the problems and solutions reproducible, it would really be best if you posted a sample MTL file somewhere accessible, or pointed to a publicly accessible one somewhere on the web.

Comment: okay.....it will be easy if you could give me your e-mail ID...because here is not possible to post though it is large lines of code....and on web it will be accessible on USGS website zipped with the data for which i have posted path and row in my last message...

Comment: Please post a **complete** URL.  The "L5...._MTL" string you gave is not even found with Google.

Answer (score 0):

for reading Mtl file along with your images (stack image) you can do the following:

1. Give the directory of you Mtl file. For example

   ```
   mtlFile<- "\\LE07_L1TP_165035_20090803_20161220_01_T1_MTL.txt"
   ```
2. Read metadata

   ```
     metaData <- readMeta(mtlFile)
     metaData
   ```
3. Load rasters based on the metadata file

   ```
    lsat <- (stackMeta(mtlFile, quantity = "all", category = "image", 
    + allResolutions = FALSE))
    lsat
    plot(lsat)
   ```